# Getting DuplicateFileException (Records would cause duplicates) when copy data in between hadoop cluster using distcp

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop2, distcp

I am copying all files from one Hadoop cluster to another Hadoop cluster using distcp. On 1st attempt copied all data but on 2nd back of data getting exception DuplicateFileException (Records would cause duplicates). for more detail check bellow log stack.

i tried 
./bin/hadoop distcp -update  hdfs://XXXXXXXXX:8020/* hdfs://XXXXXXXXX:9000/
bin/hadoop distcp -p -log -i -overwrite  hdfs://XXXXXXXXX:8020/* hdfs://XXXXXXXXX:9000/

```
 ERROR tools.DistCp: Duplicate files in input path: 
org.apache.hadoop.tools.CopyListing$DuplicateFileException: File hdfs://192.168.1.22:8020/original/10000 Sales Records and hdfs://192.168.1.22:8020/sample/10000 Sales Records would cause duplicates. Aborting
    at org.apache.hadoop.tools.CopyListing.validateFinalListing(CopyListing.java:160)
    at org.apache.hadoop.tools.CopyListing.buildListing(CopyListing.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.tools.GlobbedCopyListing.doBuildListing(GlobbedCopyListing.java:90)
    at org.apache.hadoop.tools.CopyListing.buildListing(CopyListing.java:84)
    at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.createInputFileListing(DistCp.java:382)
    at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.createAndSubmitJob(DistCp.java:181)
```

Comment: Did u found any solution on the same ?

Comment: No @Mukesh I did not get any solution for this